# Low Replace almost the same html

Tags: low-replace

I'm looking to strip some html from an img area with Low replace. This works great, but I have varying heights and widths to deal with.

So:

```
{exp:low_replace find="height=QUOTE365QUOTE|width=QUOTE500QUOTE" replace="SPACE" multiple="yes"}
```

ideally wants to be

```
{exp:low_replace find="height=QUOTE___QUOTE|width=QUOTE___QUOTE" replace="SPACE" multiple="yes"}
```

what should I put in the *_* bit for any number value? Possible?

Answer (score 2):

You, my friend, need to learn the ways of Regular Expressions. Try this:

```
{exp:low_replace
    find="(height|width)=QUOTE\d+QUOTE"
    replace="SPACE"
    regex="yes"
}
```

Comment: I knew it would have something to do with Regular Expressions (file with htaccess and Terminal.app voodoo)! You, are to clever. Thank you. It works!

Comment: Cool. Can you mark the answer as accepted, then? Ta.